Unity Instantiate ScriptableObject returns null in build mode
I am new to Unity. My Unity version is 2022.3.21f1c1.
I have a class called CardData which is inherited from ScriptableObject:
    public class CardData : ScriptableObject
    {
        public string id;
        public string title;
        // ... many other type of variables, including list, dict and objects of custom classes
    }

And then I instantiate it using
              CardData ref_card = card_list[0];
              CardData card = UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(ref_card);
              if(card.title.Contains("test"))
              {
                  Debug.Log($"ref_card.title = {ref_card.title}, ref_card = {ref_card}");
                  Debug.Log($"card.title = {card.title}, card = {card}");
              }

In Editor mode, when I press Run, the log is
ref_card.title = test1, ref_card = test (TcgEngine.CardData)

card.title = test1, card = test(Clone) (TcgEngine.CardData)

But after I built the project, the log (enable Development Build and Player Log) is
ref_card.title = test1, ref_card = test (TcgEngine.CardData)

card.title = test1, card = null

The same code, without any modification, and test many times. Why the instantiated one is null in build mode? And why I can get access to properties of null object (card is null and card.title is normal and does not throw any exception)?

I thought you had to follow the documentation and do ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<CardData>()

ScriptableObject.CreateInstance can only create empty object? I need the cloned one.

out of interest why do you need to duplicate it?

I want to let players can make their own cards. They can choose an existing card as a reference and make some modification to it.

@BugFinder Instantiate should work to create a deep clone of just any UnityEngine.Object instance
